# How do I change this code so each time I refresh the browser it doesn't delete

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I'm doing a reminder app which needs to store each task in local storage which I kind of have working except for the fact that each time you refresh the browser it deletes everything in local storage. What do I need to add/change to store the items without losing them each refresh

```
 let reminders = [];

 const addReminders = (ev) => {
     ev.preventDefault(); 
let reminder = {
    ReminderInput: document.getElementById('ReminderInput').value,
    DateInput: document.getElementById('DateInput').value,
    InfoInput: document.getElementById('InfoInput').value

}

const arr = [reminder.ReminderInput, reminder.DateInput, reminder.InfoInput]

localStorage.setItem('todoForm', JSON.stringify(arr))
reminders.push([reminder.ReminderInput, reminder.DateInput, reminder.InfoInput]);
localStorage.setItem("reminders", JSON.stringify(reminders));
}

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
     document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addReminders);
 });

<form id="todoForm">
                <label for="ReminderInput">Reminder</label>
                <input class="u-full-width" type="text" id="ReminderInput">


                <label for="DateInput">Date</label>
                <input class="u-full-width" type="datetime-local" id="DateInput">


                <label for="InfoInput">Additional Information</label>
                <textarea class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Remember to..." id="InfoInput"></textarea>
                <button type="button" id="btn" class="button-primary">Add Reminder</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you are setting reminders as an empty array.

```
let reminders = [];
```

and in this section you are setting it into the local storage

```
reminders.push([reminder.ReminderInput, reminder.DateInput, reminder.InfoInput]);
localStorage.setItem("reminders", JSON.stringify(reminders));
```

Since upon each reload reminders are set to empty array, so your data will be deleted after reload.

You need to fetch data from local storage if it exists and set to empty otherwise.

use this

```
let reminders = [];
if (localStorage.getItem('reminders')) {
  reminders = localStorage.getItem('reminders');
}
```